# Writing directly into vertex buffer

Tags: c++, directx, buffer, vertex

The DirectX 9 application/game I inherited uses dynamic vertex buffers. Each frame, it:

1. locks the vertex buffer
2. cycles through meshes and writes vertex data to a temporary buffer (dynamically allocated at program start) until it's full
3. copies the contents of the temporary buffer to the vertex buffer
4. repeats steps 2 and 3 until all data is copied
5. unlocks the vertex buffer

My question is, is the part with the temporary buffer necessary? Is there a reason why I shouldn't write vertex data directly into the vertex buffer?
I haven't found any evidence of this practice in the official documentation, and I don't trust the previous programmer enough.

Comment: I think you'd be fine writing straight to the vertex buffer...

Comment: ... although I agree it wouldn't perform as well if the locked vertex buffer were memory mapped straight onto the GPU (see leftaroundabout's answer).

Answer (score 2):

Discaimer: I don't know how DirectX vertex buffers work, I might be wrong here.

It would probably be slower: a vertex buffer is allocated to optimize *access from the GPU*, i.e. preferrably somewhere in the GPU's own memory. That means directly accessing it from the CPU is much slower than accessing ordinary RAM. Copying a whole array on the other hand can be done relatively fast, so it is better to prepare such an array in main memory and copying it to the vertex buffer in one go.

Comment: I kinda doubt the pointer you get back from LockVertexBuffer addresses straight into GPU memory.  I think it's going to be in main normally memory managed by the driver; once you unlock the vertex buffer it's free to DMA that to the card.  Unfortunately I'm not a Direct3D person either -- this is how it works in OpenGL though.

Comment: Yeah, that makes sense. — I only know GPU programming from CUDA, where you can directly access device memory, but it probably doesn't work this way in the non-hardware-specific graphics libraries.

Comment: At any rate, if no Direct3D experts come in and save the day, I think he ought to benchmark it and see what happens :)

Answer (score 2):

The temporary buffer is not required, with a caveat.

DirectX dynamic vertex buffers are optimised for *read* access by the GPU and *write* access by the CPU. The write access optimisation is called **write combining**, and involves a different mechanism than normal memory caching. The CPU will batch writes together, given that you write to the memory in 4/8/16 byte chunks and in order.

Note that it's up to the driver to decide what kind of memory you get back from a lock on a dynamic buffer, it may not be write combined, but treating it as such is the best bet.

Write combined memory is *not* cached, so reading from it is a performance disaster.

It might explain why the game you inherited uses a temporary buffer if it reads as well as writes to the temporary buffer, or makes no effort to write components in order - positions first then texture coordinates for example.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the temporary buffer. The pointer you are given back from `Lock` is, in essence, actually already a temporary buffer. The driver can only realistically begin any meaningful operations on it once you unlock the buffer.

If you use `D3DLOCK_DISCARD`, then the driver has no obligation to honour reads with any sensible data. So the implementation can perfectly well return `malloc(size)`.

If you *don't* use `D3DLOCK_DISCARD`, then, well, that's a separate question, really.